# merging package.json in git (solving version conflict)

Tags: node.js, git, package.json

We keep getting a conflict for the version field in the package.json. For instance:

```
"version": "1.1.144"
```

and:

```
"version": "1.1.145"
```

Is there a way to auto-resolve it with the highest version number?

Comment: How do you manage releases/versions ? What is your [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) ?

Comment: If you always know which one to pick you can use `--ours` or `--theirs` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: @GabrielBleu our core project is git flow. The question is regarding one of its dependencies which is a private npm package project. There are several of those. Those npm packages have a gulp build process which bumps the minor version. The merge logic for us should be - always take the bigger version number. It is not always known whether the bigger number is the local or the remote version.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-version-match) that checks for the version in the remote and sets the local version to match.

```
npm install -g node-version-match
```

and from a project's directory:

```
level
```

This will sets the local package.json version to match the remote package.json version:

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "0.0.152", // <=== sets this to equal the version in remote
 ...
```

This prevents conflicts before pulling, afterwards we change the version number, commit & push.

Comment: do you have example of how you have used ? what I am looking is similar one to happen in PRs in BitBucket.