# Package.json with GIT Workflow - Separate dependency for develop and master branch

Tags: node.js, git, npm, semantic-versioning, git-workflow

I am using GIT Workflow (develop, master, feature, release) branches for our software development. Now our software has few internal dependents packages in `package.json` coming directly from our enterprise GIT on a specific branch (e.g. `git+ssh://git@ourdomain.com:2999/coredependency.git#develop`).

Now, our current `develop` branch code is pointing to the `develop` branch of the dependent packages for QA (as shown above), the reason being, the current changes in QA may have changes on dependent packages to work and once the QA is passed, we merge the dependent packages code from their `develop` to `master` and update our `package.json` (in release branch) to point to the `master` branch of those dependencies.

Now according to the workflow, after the deployment, we are merging the release branch into master and develop and the problem is, I don't want the `package.json` pointing to `master` (in release branch) be merged into `develop` branch but only in the `master` branch with a tag.

Glimpse of my Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "core": "git+ssh://git@ourdomain.com:2999/coredependency#master",
    "intelligence": "git+ssh://git@ourdomain.com:2999/dependency2.git#feature/jk-1212",
    "notifications": "git+ssh://git@ourdomain.com:2999/dependency3.git#master",
    "social": "git+ssh://git@git.ccmteam.com:2999/cdependency4#develop",
    "gulp-cli": "2.0.1",
```

What could I do to avoid this situation? as we merge our code using Pull Requests

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to:

- push develop to your normal remote origin
- merge as usual back to develop (which may change the package.json)
- use [the node-version-match package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49643897/6309) to reset the develop package.json version back to the ones you just pushed *before* the merge.

Another approach is: if the package.json has changed after a merge, do

```
git checkout @~ -- package.json
```